# Rsync takes longer time “receiving incremental file list”

Tags: rsync

I am using rysnc to copy files from remote host to local machine using a cron job. Every time I need the rsync to copy new files only from remote host. But its getting struck at this line "receiving incremental file list" for very long time. Below is the command I am using. Is there any other way I can fasten up this rsync process?

```
rsync -avz --inplace --progress --delete -ahe ssh remoteuser@remotehost:/home/bin/dir1/data /home/bin/dir1
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with `--delete-before`, `--delete-after` or `--delay-updates`?

> Some options require rsync to know the full file list, so these options
>   disable the incremental recursion mode. These include: --delete-before, --delete-after, --prune-empty-dirs, and --delay-updates. Because of this, the default delete mode when you specify --delete is now --delete-during when both ends of the connection are at least 3.0.0 (use --del or --delete-during to request this improved deletion mode explicitly). See also the --delete-delay option that is a better choice than using --delete-after.

(from: http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync)

Comment: The quote doesn't say what the options do.

Comment: @Keith sorry for the poor answer, I was younger and inexperienced at the time. IIRC what I meant to say six years ago (!) was that if you manage to disable the internal recursion you might end having faster loading times. anyway I see from the same man page that there's a new flag called `--no-inc-recursive` made for this exact purpose.